# Creating MarkLogic REST api instance on Azure but cannot connect to it

Tags: azure, rest, marklogic

I have created some REST api instance in Marklogic virtual machine on Azure and I could see them in the list of app-servers. However, I could not connect through the port I specified as it shows it takes too long for the server to respond. I do not know what to do next.

Comment: Make sure you have whitelisted the specified port. You need to whitelist your port if you want to access outside

Comment: thank you, @RafaqatAli, it helped me solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

When you install MarkLogic Server, a pre-configured REST API instance is available on port 8000. This instance uses the Documents database as the content database and the Modules database as the modules database.

You can also use the REST Client API in conjunction with the REST Management API on port 8002.

The instance on port 8000 is convenient for getting started, but you will usually create a dedicated instance for production purposes.

Please try to use the default port and see if you are able to access your api, if yes then you have to open the incoming and outgoing traffic on your VM as rightly pointed by @Rafaqat.

For creating a new instance , you can check below doc:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_12021

Additional reference:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_12021

Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad to know it helped, please accept as an answer as it will help others who have the same ask